# Specify Subject Alternative Name when generating a self signed certificate

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

Is there a way to get a .crt and .key file with the subject alternative name set? I am configuring a proxy with an openssl .crt and .key generated by this command

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout proxy.key -out proxy.crt
```

I then cat the .key and .crt to get a .pem and use that on the client side.
This cert works fine for securing the https connection but I get a warning that the Subject Alternative Name is not set in the certificate. In another client I use the warning is actually an error that terminates the connection.

The solution here https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556 gives me a .csr which I rename to become the .crt I need, and when I use this with the client the https connection fails on incorrect ssl certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a .crt and .key file with the subject alternative name set?

Yes, but you cannot do it from the command line. You have to use a CONF file.

For setting the SAN via a CONF file, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639). Both include the SAN in the procedures.

Comment: jww, somehow when I execute the directions in the second link you send me I see that I now have a SAN field in my .crt which is great, but when I cat the cert with they key as a pem to use in my client I get a `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`. If I do the same exact openssl certificate generation but instead use the default ubuntu openssl.cnf I get a successful connection but with the warning `Certificate has no 'subjectAltName'`. So something about adding the SAN is causing verification to fail.

Comment: @HamzehAlsalhi - what user agent? Is this a browser? Or a command line tool, like `s_client`, `wget` or `cURL`?

Comment: Python requests is what I'm testing with which gives me the SAN warning, java HttpsURLConnection is the end goal but this client errors out on no SAN instead of warning.

Comment: *If* you have a certificate with a SAN, then you should probably ask a new question. It sounds like you now have a problem with Python trusting the self signed certificate. Stack Overflow likes to keep questions/answers targeted and concise. It makes it easier on future visitors.

Comment: you're right, you solved the question I originally asked so I'll accept the answer

Comment: this answer is no longer true; https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366949/3961420

Answer (score 17):

As per @vog's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366949/3961420):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" \
  -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.net,IP:10.0.0.1"
```

(note that this is only for OpenSSL >= 1.1.1).

Comment: unknown option -addext
LibreSSL 2.8.3

Comment: @PavolTravnik did you read the note (in the parentheses)?

Comment: well it is not a solution for debian nor mac natively because of openssl version - solution probably for a special setup only

Comment: @PavolTravnik Well, if you’d read the linked answer (from @vog), you would find a command that works on older versions. This question is not tagged with “Debian” nor “macOS”, so I really don’t see why you had to downvote my answer. I even specifically noted that it doesn’t work on older versions and provided a link to my source. Please reconsider.

Comment: works perfectly with pure OpenSSL on Ubuntu 21.04!   Why use Libre something, when everywhere tagged exactly openssl ?

Comment: @PavolTravnik it's you who use some custom config, works perfectly on ubuntu, centos, fedora out of box

Comment: Thank you for adding an example with multiple DNS entries, it was not so simple to find the correct syntax. Upvoted.

Comment: Worked on RHEL8

Comment: Happy to say I am seeing the `addext` option in LibreSSL 3.3.6 on Mac OS X